# V18.04.3LTS troubled boot up. Tries twice

Tags: boot

I have V18.04.3 LTS in dual boot with WIN XP.

When I select UBUNTU from the Menu it will start a boot then quit and restart  with running of the BIOS. It will then start. On reactivation from S/by it will often freeze. I then have to re-power take the menu Recovery option.
What do I do now?
Sincerely, BerryG

Comment: Check disk for errors.

Comment: What is WIN XP? :P

Comment: Have you done any clean full installs lately, or have you always done an upgrade from the system you were using at the time?  What does 'smart data' from disks say about hard drive?

Comment: Always an update. Would you advise me how to do a clean install in a way that preserves my dual boot facility with WINXP. I need to know if I need to clear the existing disk area and how to preserve my settings. Thank you for your response. BjG

Comment: WINXP is the original Windows Operating System (OS) which is preserved by having a "dual boot" facility that allows you to choose whether to run XP or Ubuntu as the OS

Comment: No I have not checked the disk area for errors. I don't believe my existing disk software will work with the UBUNTU format. It is a in two Partitions formatted to EXT4 (I think) and is invisible to my normal test software.